# Scroll to a certain element of the current page in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

Upon clicking a button (which is bottom of the page), I want to go to a certain element (in my case, #navbar) which is in the top of the current page, but I don't know how to do it. I've tried the following code with no avail.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded" id="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        {{appTitle}}
    </a>
    <!-- rest of the nav link -->
</nav>
<!-- rest of the page content -->

<!-- bottom of the page -->
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="gotoTop()">Top</button>
```

In angular component:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
 /* rest of the import statements  */
export class MyComponent {
   /* rest of the component code */
    gotoTop(){
       this.router.navigate([], { fragment: 'navbar' });
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone helped me out with a solution and explained why my code hadn't worked.

Please note that element (navbar) is in other component.

Comment: How about replacing the button with <a> tag and putting an anchor?

Comment: It won't serve my purpose. I want to use a click event. also want to do it by following strictly angular convention.

Comment: Since when Angular deprives you of the convention HTML ? That's a no sense, but respect your choice

Comment: is it necessary for you to scroll to the element or would it be just fine to scroll to the very top of your website?

Comment: In my case, it is important to scroll to a certain element. Besides that I want to use this in other scenarios.

Comment: Yah! I've tried your solution. But, couldn't make it work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212900/scroll-to-specific-div-on-click-in-angular

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this with javascript:

```
gotoTop() {
  let el = document.getElementById('navbar');
  el.scrollTop = el.scrollHeight;
}
```

This will bring the DOM element with `id="navbar"` into view when the method is called. There's also the option of using [Element.scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). This can provide a smooth animation and looks nice, but isn't supported on older browsers.

If the element is in a different component you can reference it several different ways as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template).

The easiest method for your case would likely be:

```
import { ElementRef } from '@angular/core'; // at the top of component.ts

constructor(myElement: ElementRef) { ... } // in your export class MyComponent block
```

and finally

```
gotoTop() {
  let el = this.myElement.nativeElement.querySelector('nav');
  el.scrollIntoView();
}
```

[Working plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/OU2oYtNE9yYKmuYx6jNC?p=preview)

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. Please note that element is in other component.

Comment: I got it working after using this: `this.myElement.nativeElement.ownerDocument.getElementById('navbar').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});`

Answer (score 2):

I know, you want to scroll to a specific element in the page. But, if the element is in the top of the page, then you can use the following:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("YOUR_DIV_ID").scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your way didn't work because of the empty router.

```
this.router.navigate(['/home'], { fragment: 'top' });
```

would work if 'home' is declared as a route and you have the id="top" element on it.

I know you would like it to be "pure Angular way", but this should work (at least):

```
gotoTop(){
  location.hash = "#navbar";
}
```