# Scroll to specific div on (click) in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a `#content` div and a button component.

When I click the button, I want to scroll to the top of the #content div.

---

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    Loren ipsum 
</div>
<div (click)="toTop($event)">top</div>
```

topscroll.component.ts:

```js
export class TopscrollComponent implements OnInit { 
  constructor() { } 

  ngOnInit() { }

  toTop(event){ 
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do that with plain javascript using `.scrollIntoView()`:

```
toTop() {
  document.getElementById("content").scrollIntoView();
}
```

---

*Note: you don't need `event`.*

Comment: I want to set specific id="content"...bcoz i have written scroll css only for that id

Comment: Aah, you want to scroll to the top of the `#content` div?

Comment: Yes..i am expecting that one

Comment: What does `console.log(top)` say? Is it undefined, or a number?

Comment: getting number only

Comment: Updated. Try this.

Comment: Jeffrey Roosendaal - Thank you so much..I have some more doubt in n = angular 5..How can i contact you? you have any blog?

Comment: No problem! (can you also please +1 my answer?). No, sorry, I don’t have a blog. But this may help you: *All* valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript/Angular, so you can search Google and StackOverflow for JavaScript, and it will work. Like my answer, it’s just plain JavaScript, and has nothing to do with TypeScript/Angular, but it still works fine. Good luck!

Comment: Please..can you send your mail id?