# Scroll to specific div using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll

On button click I want to scroll a specific div.
Make sure I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll / Jump to id without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266746/scroll-jump-to-id-without-jquery)

Comment: You can use a hyperlink and a hash fragment. Or you could use one of the solution linked to calculate the position of the element you want to scroll to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scroll to specific div on (click) in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51212900/scroll-to-specific-div-on-click-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

Give id for that div and use

```
document.getElementById("id").scrollIntoView();

    <div id="whatever">
       <--do things -->
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("whatever").scrollIntoView();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $anchorScroll concept in angular refer example:

```
'use strict';angular.module('anchorScrollExample', []).controller('ScrollController', ['$scope', '$location', '$anchorScroll',
function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
  $scope.gotoBottom = function() {
    // set the location.hash to the id of
    // the element you wish to scroll to.
    $location.hash('bottom');

    // call $anchorScroll()
    $anchorScroll();
  };
}]);})(window.angular);
```

Here 'bottom' is your div id where you want to scroll and 'gotoBottom(). is function on button click