# using scrollIntoView function to specific HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I'm using scrollIntoView function to click on a link and have it jump to a different part of my web app. The issue i am having is that i dont know how to target an HTML element called 'identifier'

so my html looks like...

```
<div class="subpara" identifier="2b">
            <num value="b">(B)</num>
            <content>some conent</content>
</div>
```

I want to be able to target the 'identifier' 2b in this case

i tried using:

```
  onClickOutlineNav(id) {
    let element = document.getElementById(id);
    //scroll to identifier
    element.scrollIntoView();
  }
```

and it doesnt seem to be working..any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742611/scroll-to-a-certain-element-of-the-current-page-in-angular-4

Comment: If you add `id="zzz"`  you should be able to just do `location.hash="zzz"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using incorrect html tag syntax, which would be your first problem.

```
<div class="subpara" id="2b">
```

The getElementById function looks for the "id" property on html tags, not the "identifier" property.

If you insist on using the "identifier" property, you can query for it like so:

```
let element = document.querySelector('[identifier="2b"]');
```

or more generically:

```
let element = document.querySelector(`[identifier="${id}"]`);
```

Comment: how would i use the identifier property?

Comment: How would you use it in what way? You want to query for an element by the "identifier" property instead of the "id" property?